# How to select all elements that do not contain a particular value or set of values in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have list and values:

```
selector: ".list > div"

const velue = [6, 9, 21]
```

each div contain different value. I want to rid of each element that contain a particular value, then select for instance first element and click on it. Something like this:

```
cy.get(".list > div").not('contains', value).eq(0).click()
```

I tried to handle this case using [not](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/not) but it doesnt work in that way, only accept selectors. Any idea? I cant even find similar topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` needs to be merged into the `contains` selector inside the `.not()` command.

It's actually a [pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), so format is `:contains()`

```js
cy.get(".list > div")
  .not(`:contains(${value})`)   // inject value into string template
  .eq(0)
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress comes bundled with neat utility lodash functions, one of which is [`_.filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter). You can use a callback function to filter out the `6`, `9`, and `21`.

example HTML

```html
<ul class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>21</div>
</ul>
```

Test code

```js
cy.get(".list > div")
  .then(($el) => {
    // filter out elements having '6', '9', and '21'
    // and return the array to cypress chain
    return Cypress._.filter($el, (el) => {
      const text = el.innerText;
      return text != "6" && text != "9" && text != "21";
    });
  })
```

Here is working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/findNotByCertainText.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **:not** selector, so it look like this if you want to exclude the "3" et "5"

```
cy.get('div:not(:contains("3"), :contains("5"))')
```